# RubyMine doesn't load the rbenv-vars plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, rbenv, rbenv-vars

I use `rbenv` and the `rbenv-vars` plugins. They work fine when I launch my rails server in a terminal. So nothing is wrong with my configuration or my installation.

If I launch my server from RubyMine, my environment variables aren't loaded. All the rest of my app run.

I have tested installing `rbenv` directly in my home (`with git`), or installing `rbenv` with `homebrew`, and I have tested launching RubyMine with command line. Each time leads to the same result, rbenv-vars aren't loaded.

Lastly, if I launch the integrated terminal and I run `rbenv vars`, I can read all my variables.

- **mac os** : 10.13
- **zsh** : 5.3
- rbenv ver : rbenv 1.1.1-30-gc8ba27f
- **ruby** : 2.4.1. (with rbenv isntall)
- **rbenv-vars** : 1.2.0
- **rubymine ver** (previous version are the same result) :

  - RubyMine 2018.1.3
  - Build #RM-181.4892.67
  - JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b38 x86_64
  - JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  - macOS 10.13.4

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :

In  "Run / Edit Configuraton" menu. for each rails console / server and for the development environment

Find the "Tab" Bundler and check "Run the scripting context of the bundle (bundle exec)

Restart your rails server or your rails console and TADA :)